# no funciona ms-auto, ml-auto ni mr-auto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bootstrap

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <%=title%>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="basicExampleNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto  ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="/"> <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about"><i class="fas fa-building"></i> About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

estoy viendo un tutorial de como hacer una pagina web con node js y en un momento a través de bootstrap ponen ml-auto lo cual pone los botones home, about y contact a la derecha pero no me lo toma.
en algunos foros dice uqe poneiendo mr-auto se arregla pero tampoco funciono. lo ultimo queencontre fue poniendo ms-auto lo cual si lo tira hacía la derecha pero una linea mans abajo que el titulo cuando en realidad dbee estar en el mismo. y la entrar en contact todo se pone mas grande y no se porque. les dejo el codigo ajala puedan ayudarme`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <%=title%>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="basicExampleNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto  ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="/"> <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about"><i class="fas fa-building"></i> About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>`
```

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y convertir tu código a snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`)?

Comment: hola, ahí hice lo que me pediste, por favor decime si ahi quedó como necesitas

Comment: La sugerencia del snippet fue para que puedas importar bootstrap y se pueda reproducir el problema :) ¿Utilizas la versión 4 o la 5?

Comment: Si utilizas la version 5, ahora se llaman `*-start`, `*-end` en lugar de `*-right` o `*-left`, es decir: `ms-*`  `me-*`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no te funciona porque ese curso (estoy haciendo el mismo curso) que estas haciendo se basa en bootstrap 5.
Me paso igual y cuando lo pase a bootstrap 5 me funciono.

Saludos

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/347200)